# How to trigger events based on time stamp from database - mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, express, scheduler

I have an `angular` application on front end and `express js` running on back-end. I need to provide `notifications` on front end based on meetings scheduled at particular time.

Example:

> If a meeting is scheduled today at 12:00 pm , I need to show
>   notification on front end with meeting notification depending on time
>   stamp stored in database(Mongo db).

Any little advice on back end logic is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be this one :

## First step: cron task

You make a CRON Task (https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples) which will check every minute for example if the timestamp of a meeting has passed or if in the next minute there will be a meeting (this kind of request : `SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE notified = false AND (now() > meeting_time OR now() + 1m > meeting_time)` *—this request is not valid SQL, it's just for example—*). For each of the fetched meetings, you add an new object to a `notification` collection with your notification information, and tag each notified `meeting` with a `notified=true` for example to avoid fetching already notified meetings.

## Second step: watch changes

Then you can just use the `watch()` feature of mongodb (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/) to listen your changes in `notification` and notify your front when there is a new notification. There is an example with Server Send Event (SSE) and mongodb watch : https://ryantravitz.com/2018-11-29-server-sent-events/

## See also

You can also use third party services to store your notifications like https://pusher.com/ or firebase (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/). Same principle but instead of store the notification in mongodb you send it to these services and you plug your front on endpoints given by these services.

Comment: I have used a cron job(node-cron) and events(npm package) to execute this. The cron job checks for every one minute whether any meeting is to conducted before one minute and notifies the user though websockets (socket.io) . I have also used eventemitter from events package which will be present inside the cron job and emits an alert event. another evenemitter listens which is present inside socket method listens to this event and send a notification to front end.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const checkPolls = async () => {

    let today = new Date();
    let start = today.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    let end = today.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 59);  
    console.log("End", new Date(end), "start", new Date(start));
    const condition = {
        createdAt: { $gte: new Date(start), $lte: new Date(end) },
      };

      const poll_list = await services.getList(
        Poll,
        {status: approved, condition},
        {}
      );
      console.log("New User", poll_list);
      res.send({ success: true, data: poll_list });
    
    var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
       checkPolls();
      }, null, true);
            job.start();
    }
```